# Has IntelliJ an equivalent to VS Code 'extensions.json' recommendations?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

Lately I am using sometimes VS Code and IntelliJ. The VS Code feature of recommended extensions is great for the initial setup of projects.

Is there an equivalent in the JetBrains ecosystem for Plugins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about [Workspace recommended extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions) (where you can list plugins that are needed for this project or the project/user will gain benefits from having such a plugin)?

If yes: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Required Plugins`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-required-plugins.html

[image]
*(NOTE; the screenshot is from PhpStorm. IntelliJ IDEA will have it in a similar place)*

**P.S.** On related note: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#suggested-plugins

---

**2023-01-09:** Such settings will be stored in `externalDependencies.xml` file in the `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea` folder (where other project-specific settings are stored). This file (as well as many other files there) can be put under VCS if needed. Check the following links for more info on that:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html#share-project-through-vcs
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

Comment: The vs-code recommended extensions are added in a .vscode folder and can be tracked by the vcs tool as part of the project . However, the JetBrains documentation doesn't specify how those informations (plugin required list ) are stored and shared, unless I missed something

Comment: Here only the plugins settings can be exported in an archive  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings

Comment: @RaymondA It will be stored in `externalDependencies.xml` file in the `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea` folder (where other project-specific settings are stored). This file (as well as many other in that folder) can also be put under VCS. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839 and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html#share-project-through-vcs

Comment: Thanks that clarifies everything